# Error during visual studio 2015 installation

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have this error during visual studio 2015 installation on windows server 2012 r2

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Hi Afshin, refer to the system requirement of VS 2015, please make sure you already installed update 2919355 and windows update up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus and clean up %temp% folder, re-run the installer as administrator. If this issue persists, check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315346 to register/reinstall the windows installer, check the startup type. If this service started and then stopped, see: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/error-message-windows-installer-service-on-local/8a33609b-3230-4a23-aff5-29ca44750505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running that command on cmd  `net start MSIServer`

You could check the windows installer service is working or not from the services.msc Normally it should stay at "Manual".

Comment: i have this error when i try to start windows installer                       
"Windows Installer Service on local computer started and then stopped"